# When I Re-Bundle An AMI On Amazone EC2 - Can Anybody Access It?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

Are all re-bundled AMIs available to the public? What is this about "public" and "private" AMIs? And why so much worry about leaving "your keys" on the AMI after re-bundling?

Is it safe to create an AMI with sensitive data on it? Will anybody else be able to use my AMIs in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, all created AMIs are private by default.

Yay, me.